# .map is not a function..... doesnt render table

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why it doesnt want to show me my data table?

I dont understand why it doesnt want to show my data in table. 
I consoled.log everything and in console it shows me result.
When i go to Network - preview and response it shows full json with all information, but my table is empty......

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class ProfilStudent extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
                isLoading:false,
                isError:false,
                students: []
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:8095/dnevnik/student/profil', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Basic ' + window.btoa(this.props.username + ":" + this.props.password),
                "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
                'Accept': 'application/json',
            }
        })
        .then(response => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(students => {
        this.setState({ students });
        });
    }
    renderStudents() {
        return this.state.students.map(student => {
          return (
            <tr key={student.id}>
              <td>{student.id}</td>
              <td>{student.firstName}</td>
              <td>{student.lastName}</td>
            </tr>
          );
        })
      }

    render() {
      
        return (
            <div>
               <table>
                   <thead>
                       <tr>
                           <th>ID</th>
                           <th>firstName</th>
                           <th>lastName</th>
                           <th>Username</th>
                       </tr>
                   </thead>
                   <tbody>
                       {this.renderStudents()}
                   </tbody>
              </table>
              </div>
            );  
        }     
}
export default ProfilStudent;
```

I have tryed everything. Searched all info on internet, stackoverflow, but still have this problem
I have same code in other class and works perfectly.
What is the reason here, please, help!!!

Comment: Could you explain what version of Java this is? Looks strange

Comment: how to you mean what version of Java

Comment: You added a `Java` tag to your question, when this question has nothing to do with Java. It seems you accidentally added it. I have edited the question to remove it.

Comment: On a more serious note, can you post your response? It's probably an object and map is applicable to arrays.

Comment: {id: 1, firstName: "Milan", lastName: "M",…}
firstName: "Milan"
id: 1
lastName: "M"
parent: {id: 3, firstName: "Marko", lastName: "M"}

firstName: "Marko"
id: 3
lastName: "M"

Comment: TypeError: this.state.students.map is not a function

Comment: Have you confirmed that `this.state.students` is an array?

Answer (score 0):

THANK you.
I was sooo tired that i didnt notice that i have objects instead array so i made array of my response and now map works.
Thanks everybody